# Trigger in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to create a trigger in SQL Server 2008 R2. I have three tables and they have PK-FK -FK relationship.

I have a column in first table where column name is `STATUS` that column has value 'inactive' or 'active' and in second table I have column `FKNEWLoanreviewfieldid` which has multiple values C2,C4,C6 and in third table I have `FKWarningtypeID` has different value like 4,3,2,1.

I have to create a trigger so that if `FKwarningtypeID` is updated to value 4 then in first table (where I have `status` column) the column value of `status` will be modified to 'active'.

Can any body help me please.

Comment: Also: you're not very clear in your question: can you post the relevant pieces of the tables? The table names, their key columns (name and datatype), how they are connected in terms of FK relationships?

Comment: http://okayguru.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/types-of-triggers-and-creating-triggers.html

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_UpdateYourColumn 
FOR UPDATE ON dbo.YourThirdTableHere
AS
    -- update the first table 
    UPDATE 
        dbo.YourFirstTableHere
    SET 
        -- set [Status] to 'Active'
        -- (I sure hope this isn't *REALLY* stored as a *STRING* value!)
        [Status] = 'Active'   
    FROM 
        dbo.YourFirstTableHere t1
    INNER JOIN 
        -- join first and second table on some common column            
        dbo.YourSecondTableHere t2 ON t1.XX = t2.XX  
    INNER JOIN 
        -- join second and third table on some common column
        dbo.YourThirdTableHere t3 ON t2.YY = t3.YY  
    INNER JOIN 
        -- join third table with the "Inserted" pseudo table
        Inserted i ON t3.ID = i.ID    
    INNER JOIN 
        -- join third table with the "Deleted" pseudo table
        Deleted d ON t3.ID = d.ID
    WHERE
        i.FKwarningtypeID = 4        -- new value is 4
        AND d.FKwarningtypeID <> 4   -- old value was *NOT* 4
```

Comment: @Sakil: if it worked and solved your problem, then please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/153998). It's the right and polite thing to do on SO. Thanks.